# Как фильтровать массив объектов?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив объектов. Товар покупается, и в массив попадает новый объект.
Как убрать повторения этих объектов?

```
[
    {id: "1", categoryId: "1", name: "Apple iPhone 5c", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta", price: 823, …}
    {id: "2", categoryId: "1", name: "Apple iPhone 6", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta", price: 953, …}
    {id: "4", categoryId: "5", name: "Nokia Lumia 1520", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta", price: 674, …}
    {id: "1", categoryId: "1", name: "Apple iPhone 5c", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta", price: 823, …}
    {id: "1", categoryId: "1", name: "Apple iPhone 5c", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta", price: 823, …}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо так:

```
var newArray = array.filter((element, index, array) => {
    return array.map(mapObj => mapObj['id']).indexOf(element['id']) === index;
});
```

```js
var array = [{
  id: "1",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 5c",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 823
}, {
  id: "2",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 6",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 953
}, {
  id: "4",
  categoryId: "5",
  name: "Nokia Lumia 1520",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 674
}, {
  id: "1",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 5c",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 823
}, {
  id: "1",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 5c",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 823
}];

var newArray = array.filter((element, index, array) => {
  return array.map(mapObj => mapObj['id']).indexOf(element['id']) === index;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{
  id: "1",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 5c",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 823
}, {
  id: "2",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 6",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 953
}, {
  id: "4",
  categoryId: "5",
  name: "Nokia Lumia 1520",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 674
}, {
  id: "1",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 5c",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 823
}, {
  id: "1",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 5c",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 823
}]
var result = []
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
    if (k != i) {
      if (arr[i].id == arr[k].id) arr[k] = ''
    }
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == '') continue
  else result.push(arr[i])
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  id: "1",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 5c",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 823
}, {
  id: "2",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 6",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 953
}, {
  id: "4",
  categoryId: "5",
  name: "Nokia Lumia 1520",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 674
}, {
  id: "1",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 5c",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 823
}, {
  id: "1",
  categoryId: "1",
  name: "Apple iPhone 5c",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…cies rutrum. Aliquam euismod lacus non est egesta",
  price: 823
}];

var uniqueItems = [];
//----------------------------------------------------------------

data.forEach(function (v, i) { 
    var ff = uniqueItems.find(e => v.name == e.name); // Find same element in uniqueItems
    // Not found push
    if(!ff) uniqueItems.push(v);
})

//----------------------------------------------------------------

console.log(uniqueItems);
```